# How to fetch images from folder?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a folder named as `images`.  I just want to fetch those images from the folder and show them randomly on web page.  When the user refreshes the page, the image should change.
Thank you.

Comment: please specify which languages you want to use

Comment: you can use function glob, http://php.net/glob

Comment: A google search found this: http://ma.tt/scripts/randomimage/

Answer (score 2):

An idea could be:

1. you fetch all the images names frome the images folder
2. you randomly pick one
3. you visualize that one

so you can go like this

```
<?
    $dir = '/my_directory_location'; 
    $files = scandir($dir);  
    $rand_img = array_rand($files, 2);
    $imcolumn = "<img src=$rand_img alt=$rand_img><br>";
?>

<?= $imcolumn ?>
```

Comment: <?= $imcolumn ?> what is this>

Comment: it is the output. It is a shortcut for the echo function

Comment: do you have something in output or nothing? Try to echo each different step of the procedure I showed you

Comment: <?php 
    $dir = '/images1'; 
    $files = scandir($dir);  
    $rand_img = array_rand($files, 2);
    $imcolumn = "<img src=$rand_img alt=$rand_img><br>";
?>
i did like this.. but it shows me too much error!!

Comment: I intended something different: write `echo "$dir"` after the line which begins with `$dir`, then write `echo "$files"` aftr the line which begins with `$files`... and so on, so you understand where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $folder = "templates/images/";

  $search = glob($folder."/*");
  shuffle($search);

  foreach ($search as $image) {
    print "<img src='".$image."'><Br>";
  }

?>
```